# What += and -= do in this code?

Tags: c#

I am new to wpf and mvvm concept. Here there is a [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) I am studying but I cannot understand this part;
In Figure 7:

```
 protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        MainWindow window = new MainWindow();

        // Create the ViewModel to which 
        // the main window binds.
        string path = "Data/customers.xml";
        var viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel(path);

        // When the ViewModel asks to be closed, 
        // close the window.
        EventHandler handler = null;
        handler = delegate
        {
            viewModel.RequestClose -= handler;
            window.Close();
        };
        viewModel.RequestClose += handler;

        // Allow all controls in the window to 
        // bind to the ViewModel by setting the 
        // DataContext, which propagates down 
        // the element tree.
        window.DataContext = viewModel;

        window.Show();
    }
```

What are `viewModel.RequestClose -= handler;` and `viewModel.RequestClose += handler;` doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribing and unsubscribing events.

`viewModel.RequestClose += handler;` means whenever RequestClose event is raised, the delegate defined in handler will be called.

`viewModel.RequestClose -= handler` unsubscribes it

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx#Anchor_0

Answer (score 7):

`viewModel.RequestClose += handler;` adds the `EventHandler` to the RequestClose event. `-=` removes it.

Note that removing it is done as a cleanup, since it looks like the very next thing done in the handler is to close the window.

`MainWindowViewModel` is an object that publishes an event called `RequestClose`. Your code is subscribing to that event. Your code wants to handle when that event is fired. You do that by adding a handler to the event, using `+=`. When you do that, and the `MainWindowViewModel` instance fires the event, your handler runs. Events allow a sort of decoupled form of communication between objects. It looks like your handler is also going to close the window, so it takes further action to clean up by removing the handler from the event, with `-=`.

See the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx) docs for Events.

> Events enable a class or object to notify other classes or objects when something of interest occurs. The class that sends (or raises) the event is called the publisher and the classes that receive (or handle) the event are called subscribers.

Comment: specifically, += essentially means, keep the original contents of the object on the left, and append the thing on the right, and -= means keep the contents of the thing on the left, except for the thing on the right, it's a shortcut for var1 = var1 + var2.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. But I cannot understand the code. Can you explain it a little bit? What is RequestClose and why it adds Event handler to it?

Comment: @AldenBe: I already know that. But I cannot understand how it works with event handlers.

Comment: @Saeid - I've added a little bit of info... see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Think `EventHandler`s like a set of functions that'll be executed when an event occurs.

```
Market.SoldEvent += StockRemovalEvent;
Market.SoldEvent += PaymentReceivedEvent;

if(Market.SoldOut)
{
    // we don't need it anymore.
    Market.SoldEvent -= StockRemovalEvent;
}
```

Reference Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I would appreciate for any link or resource you could provide for further study.